# lines between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

my question is if there is an "easy" way to draw a line between each node of a square with every node of the other squares which have been drawn symmetrically, here is the code of what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(90:3)}, rotate=45]
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)--(\x+90:1);};
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)node[circle, fill=blue!20, draw]{};};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(210:3)}, rotate=165]
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)--(\x+90:1);};
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)node[circle, fill=blue!20, draw]{};};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(330:3)}, rotate=285]
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)--(\x+90:1);};
    \foreach \x in{0,90,180,270}{\draw[blue] (\x:1)node[circle, fill=blue!20, draw]{};};
  \end{scope}
  %\foreach \x in{90,210,330}{\draw[thin] (0,0)--(\x:3);};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Considering that the existing answer is not exactly what you're after, it would be of much help if you could add some images of the diagram(s) you want to typeset, so that it becomes more clear which edges should be connected exactly and which variations of such diagrams you would like to create.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it is not enterally clear (to me) how dots between rectangles should be connected. Something like this?

[image]

If not, please provide a sketch which show what you after.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance =6mm and 12mm,
dot/.style = {circle, draw=blue, fill=blue!20, inner sep=2pt},
  N/.style = {draw=blue, minimum size=10mm, node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N]; 
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n1-\j) [dot] at (n1.\i) {};
\node (n2) [N, above right=of n1];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n2-\j) [dot] at (n2.\i) {};
\node (n3) [N, below right=of n2];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n3-\j) [dot] at (n3.\i) {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw[very thin, teal]  (n1-\i) -- (n2-\i)
                        (n2-\i) -- (n3-\i);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw[very thin, teal]  (n1-\i) to[bend right=15] (n3-\i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
According to your comment, t5his is starting point which show how you can connect dots from one rectangle to all dots in other rectangles:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance =6mm and 12mm,
dot/.style = {circle, draw=blue, fill=blue!20, inner sep=2pt},
  N/.style = {draw=blue, minimum size=10mm, node contents={}}
                        ]
\node (n1) [N];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n1-\j) [dot] at (n1.\i) {};
\node (n2) [N, above right=of n1];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n2-\j) [dot] at (n2.\i) {};
\node (n3) [N, below right=of n2];
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {north west, north east, south east, south west}
    \node (n3-\j) [dot] at (n3.\i) {};

\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw[very thin, teal]  (n1-1) -- (n2-\i)
                        (n1-1) to[bend right] (n3-\i)
                        %
                        (n1-2) -- (n2-\i)
                        (n1-2) to[bend right] (n3-\i);
% etc. for connections of other dots I left to you
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I'm looking for... here each node is connected with its corresponding node in the other squares, but what I want is to connect it with every node in every square

Comment: @JRV, than please make your question more clear.  Anyway, answer shoe show con do this yourself --- just add missing arrows.

Comment: @JRV, see addendum.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience and I hope to be clear this time... it works fine what you suggest, but I want to apply it in a more general context and I don't know how to do that, for example, instead of squares to have regular pentagons or hexagons whose positions are vertices of another regular polygon, as a square or any other, that's why my original code was written as it is

Comment: @JRV, sory, for this is not exist general way (different what I show you), at least to my knowledge.